# Backbone: Passing variables from router to view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a backbone router that has

```
@collection = new Backbonedemo.Collections.Posts()
@flashes = new Backbone.Collection.Flashes()
```

in its `initialize` method.

In the router's `new` method, there's this:

```
new: ->
  view = new Backbonedemo.Views.PostsNew(collection: @collection, flashes: @flashes)
  $('#posts_container').html(view.render().el)
```

The `@collection` variable passes in just fine, but in `render()`, `console.log @flashes` returns `undefined`.

So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@flashes` variable is passed as an option. So you must try something like this: `console.log @this.options.flashes`